# How to change the color of the control through code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the `color picker control provided by jscolor.com`

I don't know if this is a bug of the control or this function missing but I'm trying to update the color of the control through code. For example I set the hex color in the input text with this function:

```
function SetColor()
{
     var hex = "#B85CFF";
     document.getElementById('risorse-colore').value = hex;
}
```

the value of the input is changed correctly but the background remain to the previous color, for example if I load the page for the first time I get the white background on the input, after the function execution the color isn't changed, the only value changed is the hex inside the input. I don't know if I get the idea. Anyway, this is my control structure:

```
<input class="color" id="risorse-colore">
```

The smart way that I'm tried is JQuery:

```
$('#risorse-colore').change( function() 
{
    //Some stuff?
});
```

But the change event isn't fired and also I don't know how to simulate the changement of the color and so update the background of the input. Someone could help me?

Comment: http://jscolor.com/try.php As i can see, bgr color is automatically changed?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1ef0rxkn/  Check fiddle - no need for additional code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use style or css in jquery to apply background color. You can run the snippet, by enter any value into textbox will update its background color

```js
function SetColor()
{
     var hex = "#B85CFF";
     document.getElementById('risorse-colore').value = hex;
  $('#risorse-colore').attr('style','background-color:'+hex);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="color" id="risorse-colore" onkeydown='SetColor()'>
```

Comment: Good! But if I want pass the hex variable on background-color? Like: $('#risorse-colore').attr('style','background-color:' + hex); the style isn't applied why?

Comment: I have updated the code like passing hex value as variable, its working.